# How to backup an Azure SQL Server database and restore in sql server in a physical server

Tags: sql-server, azure

We have SQL server database in Azure SQL Server instance. I want to backup the database onto a local hard drive and restore it to a physical server. How can I do this?

It seems backup is disabled in Azure SQL Server?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You got a few options to move the data:

- You can use the [Azure Database Migration Assistant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/dma/dma-overview) tool to migrate your data from one database to another.

[image: DMA - Migrate DB]

- You can also export the database in Azure Sql to a .bacpac file, stored in an Azure Storage blob. See this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-export) for more info. You can then download the file and import the .bacpac file in SSMS localy.

  For reference, a .bacpac file is a ZIP file with an extension of 'bacpac' containing the metadata and data from a SQL Server database.

[image: Azure SQL - Export]

Comment: I have SQL Server Management Studio in one of my physical server and connected this instance. Can I get the backpac file by right clicking  on the database and select tasks --> Export Data Tier Application? Or is there a different way to do from SSMS?

Comment: @MayuranParathalingam, you can use SSMS to create and restore bacpac files from SSMS for both Azure SQL DB and on premises installations.

Comment: Thanks Rob and Kim